# find vector which describes parallel translation

Tags: geometry, vectors, linear-transformations

suppose we have following Parabola
$y=x^2+4x+6$

our goal is to find  vector which describes parallel translation of  given parabola into new one  $y=x^2$
to find vertex of the parabola, i    set two equation

$x=-b/2a=-4/2=-2$

$y=(-2)^2+4*(-2)+6=2$

for the parabola $y=x^2$ we have following vertexes 
$(0,0$) , so does it means that our vectors coordinates are $(2,-2)$ ?

Comment: You approach is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We look for $(a,b)$ such that

$$\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$$

$$(x,y)\in P_1\implies (x+a,y+b)\in P_2$$
or
$$y=x^2+4x+6 \implies x^2+4x+6+b=(x+a)^2=x^2+2ax+a^2$$

$$\implies a=2, b+6=4.$$

the translation vector is $\vec{u}=(2,-2)$.